# Select $id from ids field containg $id1,$id2,$id3

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

My model in Laravel has a linked_ids string field like this:
`echo $model->linked_ids`
`1,2,3,4,5`
I want to make a query that gets me all records with a given id in linked_ids.
Currently I have:
`Model::where('linked_ids', 'LIKE', '%' . $model->id . '%');`
but this selects me more than I want to (if ex: $model->id is 3 => selects: 1,32,67)\

How can I avoid this since I don't know what position the id will be nor will the ids be ordered? I would like to do this in eloquent but can also use something like DB::raw() to run sql queries.

Comment: `Model::whereIn('linked_ids', [1,2,3,4,5]);` should do it

Comment: So `linked_ids` is a `varchar` containing a list of IDs? That's a bad data approach, and you should consider normalizing this into proper relational tables

Comment: Firstly I didn't make it this way and also @TimLewis id in linked_ids refers to the same model type. As in this record is related to these other records of the same type.

Comment: @krisgjika you can do relations with the same model in Laravel: [here is a valid example of a one to many relationship on the same model](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/one-to-many-relationship-with-a-same-model)

Comment: I never said I blamed you for the state of the data; I've adopted code that was in this shape before, but like I said, consider changing it. Also, you can have a pivot between the same table; `model_links`, `modle_a_id`, `model_b_id`, with `6, 1`, `6, 2`, `6, 3`, etc. A CSV column like this is going to be very difficult and inefficient to query against, as you've discovered by retrieving ID `32` when you wanted `3`.

Comment: @TimLewis I will check the same model relations since I had never thought that was a thing.

Comment: Sounds good! I thought about it a bit more, you can _kinda_ make this work with your data structure. Say you have Model `id: 6`, with linked IDs `'1,2'`, this query should work: `Model::whereIn('id', explode(',', Model::find(6)->linked_ids'))->get();`; you'd have to fetch the record from the DB, explode the `linked_ids` and query against `id`. But the point still stands in that you can't query against `linked_ids` effectively.

Comment: (Woops, slight syntax error in there, extra `'` after `linked_ids`, can't edit at this point)

Comment: @krisgjika I think I finally understand what you need to do. You want to get all the models where the current model id appears in the linked_ids list. I decided to remove my answer based on this because it will definitely not aid your cause. You should look into making use of same model relations for being able to effectively query for those models.

Comment: or you can try having a look at [FIND_IN_SET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594450/find-in-set-in-laravel-example): `DB::table("models")->select("id")->whereRaw("find_in_set('3',linked_ids)")`

Comment: @CornelRaiu can this be done with a raw query using regex?

Comment: @krisgjika it [seems so](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-regexp-in-where)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007648/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-the-where-clause-of-query-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad way to keep your ids but if you really can't change it, you could take advantage of `LazyCollections` and filter with php.

I'm sure there's a way to do it directly in MySQL (or whatever dbms you're using) but this is what I have.

```php
$id = 3;
Model::cursor()
    ->filter(function ($model) use ($id) {
        return in_array($id, explode(',',  $model->linked_ids));
    })
    // then chain one of these methods
    ->first();    // returns the first match or null
    ->collect();  // returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection of the results after the filtering
    ->all();      // returns an array of Models after the filtering
    ->toArray();  // returns an array and transforms the models to arrays as well.
    ->toJson();   // returns a json string
```

Take notice that this will **still** do a `SELECT * FROM table` without any filtering (unless you chain some where methods before `cursor()` but it won't load any model into memory (which is usually the bottleneck for big queries in Laravel)